# what is the hebrew word for new, renewed, fresh, etc

Tags: hebrew

If the ancient Hebrew word CHaDaSH means NEW, then what is the Hebrew word for RENEWED?
If the ancient Hebrew word CHaDaSH means RENEWED, then what is the Hebrew word for NEW?

Comment: Are you using "renewed" as a noun or verb?

Comment: i was actually thinking of an adjective, but then again, it does not really matter. any noun or verb or adjective that is used in tanakh and/or gemara that differientiates between new and renewed.

Comment: often the differentiation is not in the word "new" but in the object -- if it preexisted, it could be renewed; if it never existed, it would be new. So even if the same ch-d-sh form is used, the word could mean "renewed".

Answer (score 1):

CHaDaSH means "new". MeCHuDaSH means "renewed".

Edited to add, upon request: The word "Chadash" is used to refer to the laws of not eating new grain - as in, grain that was (insert step in grain production here - I don't know the details) after the most recent Pesach.

The Gemara refers to this with the statement:
תנן התם החדש אסור מן התורה
in Kidushin 38b.
The word "chadash" can't possibly mean renewed here, because there's nothing renewed about the grain - it's just new grain.

I don't have a Biblical source for the fact that "mechudash" means renewed, but it might not even be a Biblical term. But morfix translates it as renewed: http://www.morfix.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9

Comment: thank you. please reference your answer with a Tanakh and/or Gemara passage.